# How do two things with one key press Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I run two commands with one `screen.onkeypress`?
Here's an example of what I'm asking;

```
def commandtwo():
    run_second_command()

def commandone():
    run_first_command()

screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(#Here I want to run both commands by pressing one key)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you not just do:

```
def do_commands():
    run_first_command()
    run_second_command()
screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(do_commands)
```

Comment: This was my initial thought as well. I think the code he used may be an oversimplified version of how he's trying to apply this. If he needs to be able to run each function independently, but also have a button that calls both functions? His example does show that each function simply makes another function call though, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a command to call the other two?

```
def button_action():
    commandone()
    commandtwo()


def commandtwo():
    run_second_command()

def commandone():
    run_first_command()

screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(button_action, key=KEY)
```

Or a worse idea would be to chain them?

```
def commandtwo():
    run_second_command()

def commandone():
    run_first_command()
    commandtwo()

screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(commandone, key=KEY)
```

Answer (score -1):

You will want to do this code. Make sure that screen.listen goes after the onkeypress method because the screen needs to have focus in order to captures those presses, like the [turtle docs] (https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/turtle.html#turtle.onkeypress) say

```
def do_commands():
    run_first_command()
    run_second_command()
screen.onkeypress(do_commands())
screen.listen()
```